# Implementing Button onClickView inside a class that extends OnClickItemListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have a `class` that `extends` `Fragment` and `implements` `OnClickItemListener`, for a gridview.
I need to add 3 clickable buttons inside this `class`, but the `OnClick(View v)` cannot be implemented because the `class` implements `OnClickItemListener`. In my `XML` layout the buttons are inside a `LinearLayout`.

 
How can I implement this so it works?

Thank you.

Comment: you can implement multiple interface just like below implements OnItemClickListener,OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, you will need to set the click listener on the buttons. This means that you will have to find the buttons in the view (probably in `onCreateView`) and then call `view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())`. If you want the fragment to be this listener, add another interface `class fragment implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener` and then when you find the view call `view.setOnClickListener(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you have already implemented `OnItemClickListener` you will override

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

method,

For `OnClickListener` you will implement

```
onClick(View v)
```

method,

So these two different methods from different interfaces wont cause any conflict. Also you can implement more than single interfaces in java. So implementing OnClickListener interface wont cause any problem.

Ref :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: Is working now.  I put in onCreateView                                                    Button llNew= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.llNew);
 llNew.setOnClickListener(this);  and I create the public void onClick(View v) ... somewhere in the class. Thank you!!